# Dimension of the null space of a compact perturbation of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, self-adjoint-operators

Let $L$ and $L_0$ be unbounded self-adjoint operators on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ such as $L$ is a compact perturbation of $L_0$.
I was wondering if it is possible to deduce an upper or lower bound on the dimension of the null space of $L$ from the dimension of the null space of $L_0$?

In fact, I am having trouble understanding the proof of lemma $4.3$, found in the article "Nonlinear stability of Mkdv breathers" by M. Alejo and C. Munoz.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that $L$ being a compact perturbation of $L_0$ means that $L - L_0$ is a compact operator?

Comment: In fact, L-L_0 is an L-compact operator (see definition 7.24 in https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~pankrashkin/2014spec/notes41.pdf)

Comment: So, it can be a compact operator, but the notion is more general

Comment: You can start with a selfadjoint operator $L_0$ with continuous spectrum only, and perturb by an arbitrarily small compact operator in order to obtain an operator with only point spectrum.